# How to convert git command to yarn particularly the git remote add origin?

Tags: git, yarnpkg

I just recently started using yarn with gh-pages. How to convert this command to yarn:

```
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/gitusername/react-gh-pages.git
```

this doesn't work: `$ yarn remote add https://github.com/gitusername/react-gh-pages.git`

Comment: I don't think that's something yarn can do. Why should it? Yarn is not a replacement for git.

Comment: @FelixKling I'm using yarn for create-react-app and I'm following the instructions here: https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages for uploading static site to gh-pages however I don't know how to convert npm commands to yarn.

Comment: Those instructions doesn't mention `yarn remote add`. Again, why do you want to add a remote to yarn?

Comment: There is often a 1:1 equivalence between npm and yarn commands. You can find a list of all commands at https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/. But yarn is not a replacement for **git**, which is what your question is about. Those commands don't change. You continue to use git.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Because i am using "yarn create react-app myapp", "yarn add" to install packages, i want to know how to add a remote origin with yarn command.

Comment: And what would "add a remote origin" do for yarn?